# Jquery "THIS".myFuntionName is unavailable when in ajax Success? but ok before

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help, I have an issue with the keyword this.. before entering the ajax call it's available but when entering Success. my "this" is available but doesn't contain the same info i.e. a method I wish to call.. This example shows what I mean..

I would appreciate any help, this.isoDateReviver is available before doing ajax.. and then when success arrives .. this.isoDateReiver is UNDEFINED

```
var data = new Object();
data.year = this.today = new Date().getFullYear();

this.isoDateReviver("yes", "yes");                //// THIS WORKS HERE

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyService.aspx/GetHolidays",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var holidays = JSON.parse(msg.d,
            this.isoDateReviver);             // THIS DOES NOT WORK its undefined

        Calendar.initalizeHolidays(holidays);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its because the success function is executed in a different scope.

you need to do:

```
var me = this;

$.ajax({
    // etc
success: function(msg) {
    var holidays = JSON.parse(msg.d, me.isoDateReviver);
```

Answer (score 0):

see: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations

the function called on success is not working in the same context as the previous call to this.isoDateReceiver.